# ADB shell command to set default Bluetooth volume for android device

Tags: android, adb, amazon-fire-tv

can someone please give me a command to make android device Bluetooth volume to default(some 11).

The below query working but the volume is going back to normal once the device is restart.

Enter command:
service call audio 7 i32 6 i32 15 i32 10​